Minor Edit - ° to degrees
I noticed in this answer, there was a minor edit:

This edit in my opinion seems redundant and unnecessary. More importantly, it was approved. I would like to know why was this edit allowed and in general, are such edits allowed?

The edit changed superscripted letter oh (<sup>o</sup>) to the word degrees with the edit summary "incorrect use of text". Typographically, OP should've used the proper degree symbol °, so the edit indeed points out a formatting issue.
The edit, however

breaks the initial intent of not using a spelled out unit, rather the unit symbol itself;
the summary is too brief and borderline wrong;
probably not worth submitting if it is only about changing a single minor formatting issue.

So, the edit likely should've been declined and a proper degree symbol should've been used. I went ahead and fixed this.

Funny enough the next edit reintroduced the degree. I actually approved it, since it fixed the links to the DOI format. Still, I changed back to °.

Yes, the next edit reintroduced the word degree (as opposed to the symbol). Andselik's edit did not add to the conversation whereas the edit corrected the reading. Roll-back was an inappropriate action - compare Your edit gets rejected, then the reviewer who rejected the edit does essentially your edit...?
